# Why does get_posts only show results for Admins or logged-out users?

Tags: wp-query, themes, user-roles, get-posts, user-access

I use a `get_posts()` call with these arguments:

```
array(6) {
    ["include"]=> string(14) "1633,1634,1635"
    ["post_status"]=> string(3) "any"
    ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment"
    ["post_mime_type"]=> string(5) "image"
    ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC"
    ["orderby"]=> string(8) "post__in"
}
```

While **logged out** or logged in as an **Admin**, **it works fine** and returns the objects for 3 images. However, when the **user is just a Subscriber/Author/Editor/Contributor, it returns an empty array**.

All plugins enabled/disabled doesn't make a difference.

When switching the theme to an official WP theme, the **error no longer persists**.

I've dumped all hooks using [this](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/debug-wordpress-hooks/) (one logged in with subscriber, one with admin), but I find no considerable difference. [Case A](http://https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Thefirsh/3175b3aab22d3edb61ee/raw/197dfcf21f563ff10704f7e73f3ee00ef5407c6b/a.txt) / [Case B](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Thefirsh/3175b3aab22d3edb61ee/raw/197dfcf21f563ff10704f7e73f3ee00ef5407c6b/b.txt). I was assuming that the theme alters my arguments to an extent that there are no results for the altered query. If it's still the case, how and where should it do that?

The theme is Javo Directory.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a new WP_Query, when you use get_posts you're using the main WP_Query this has hooks that other plugins can use to alter the query.
something else i saw is that you're using include key which is not valid

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post__in'       => array( 1633, 1634, 1635 ),
  'post_status'    => 'any',
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'orderby'        => 'post__in'
) );
```

Comment: Hi, include is valid for `get_posts()`, it's a bit different from WP_Query. However this didn't work either. It's not the method of querying posts, but rather something that prevents showing the results. The `var_dump($my_query->get_posts());` returns an empty array. When I switch the user role to Administrator it works, similar to my original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_set_current_user($user_id);` befor calling `get_posts()` to set desired user, i.e. user with sufficient privileges.
See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user

Comment: While this would probably work around the issue, it may have a lot of unintended side-effects and possibly open up some security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

just had the same issue.
In my case it was very banal to solve:
I used W3C Total Cache on this site.

> Performance > "Purge all caches" and the query got it's newest results...